# Send namespaced data from Service to Client in Java

Tags: java, service, namespaces, client

Consider I have a bunch of data processors extending the same interface :
**IProcessor.java**

```
public interface IProcessor() {
  void processName(String name);
}
```

**BookProcessor.java**

```
public class BookProcessor implements IProcessor {
  @Override
  public void processName(String name){
    //Process name in book specific logic
  }
}
```

**MagazineProcessor.java**

```
public class MagazineProcessor implements IProcessor {
  @Override
  public void processName(String name){
    //Process name in magazine specific logic
  }
}
```

All of these processors reside in a client, say `MyClient` and this client receives data from a service, say `MyService`.

I want to implement namespacing so that from this namespacing, `MyClient` can pick up the correct processor automatically. For this I was thinking `MyService` itself should send namespaced data (maybe namespaced id). 
My question how do I implement this namesapcing so that both `MyService` and `MyClient` are sharing it even when `MyService` has no knowledge about the processors that are present in `MyClient`.

Answer (score 0):

When `MyService` sends data to `MyClient`, it has to provide a hint on what type of data it's sending. So that `MyClient` can pick up the right processor for this type of data.

So the right approach would be:

Make a contract between a client and the server which states what type of data the server can send. And then, on the client side, you should implement a matcher, which matches a data type to its processor.

So that `MyService` does not know anything about data processors a client can use. It just knows what it's sending.